# tm_map to removewords containing my stop words?

Tags: r, tm

I'm applying `removeWords` to filter a corpus like this:

```
corpus <- Corpus(vs, readerControl = list(language="en")) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"))) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, bannedWords$V1)
```

However, that is only matching work **exactly**, so:

- f*ck is removed
- f*cking is not removed

How can I removeWords that **contain** my stopwords?

Comment: Not sure about `tm`, but if you're OK with involving an additional package, `quanteda` has a function `selectFeatures` (and the related `removeFeatures`) that allows use of regex and glob-type wildcards.  See `?quanteda::selectFeatures` for some examples.

Comment: Seconded on Quanteda. Its much more straightforward than tm. WIll be standard for text processing in r soon enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the `tm` library [source code](https://github.com/cran/tm/blob/master/R/transform.R) for the removeWords function and extending the regex from:

```
gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b",
```

to

```
gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b[a-zA-Z]*(%s)[a-zA-Z]*\\b",
```

The complete function

```
removeWordsContaining <-
function(x, words)
    UseMethod("removeWordsContaining", x)
removeWordsContaining.character <-
function(x, words)
    gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b[a-zA-Z]*(%s)[a-zA-Z]*\\b",
                 paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE), collapse = "|")),
         "", x, perl = TRUE)
removeWordsContaining.PlainTextDocument <-
    content_transformer(removeWordsContaining.character)

blog_corpus <- Corpus(vs, readerControl = list(language="en")) 
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, stripWhitespace) 
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, removePunctuation) 
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, removeNumbers) 
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"))) 
blog_corpus <- tm_map(blog_corpus, removeWordsContaining, bannedWords$V1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stemming to bring the banned words back to their base form. See the examples below.

```
library(tm)

banned <- c("buck")
text <- c("He is bucking the trend", "A buck is not worth a dollar anymore!")

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text), readerControl = list(language="en")) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"), banned)) 

writeLines(as.character(corpus[[1]]))
  trend
```

if you do not stem the document you will get:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text), readerControl = list(language="en")) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"), banned)) 

writeLines(as.character(corpus[[1]]))
  bucking  trend
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'll test the stemming to ensure `motherbucker` is stemmed correctly :)

Comment: I think you will have to add that one to the banned list. This is not an official verb. The stem will be motherbuck :-). Adding that to the banned list will work. See also the difference in `stopwords("english")` and `stopwords("smart")` and how the stems are used.